# Closing a question which is answered in a comment?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Sometimes a question is answered already in a series of comments. In this case the OP got the information needed and often that is the end of it, that is, there is no explicit answer which can be accepted. So, questions remain open for an arbitrary amount of time.

How can this be remedied? 
What procedure exists to initiate a closing of such questions?

Comment: This can be remedied by providing an answer(?)

Comment: See [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments) and [other related posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1148).

Comment: BTW on SE sites the phrase *closing a question* has a specific meaning: Questions are closed if they are off-topic, duplicates, missing context, etc. You probably mean that the question is still shown as [unanswered](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/unanswered-questions/info), despite actually having an answer in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with answers in comments.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) and/or [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: I apologise because my question seems to have been already asked and answered! Thank you very much for the *many* references; I did not find them before. So this is also a question that was answered in a comment ;-)